# How to show and dismiss ViewControllers without the user seeing

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have several view which I show and dismiss, but it is visible when a view moves onto screen and is dismissed from the screen.

How do I set it to just appear without any animation?

I have tries the animation:NO, it doesnt change anything.

Are there special calls for different animation types?

Comment: What types of views are these? It is difficult to answer this question without more technical specifics.

Comment: Viewcontrollers. question edited :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are wanting to present a view controller modally (ie, without using a `UINavigationController`) you would use the following:

```
-(IBAction)myButtonThatDisplaysOtherView:(id)sender {
    //where myOtherViewController is a UIViewController...
    [self presentModalViewController:myOtherViewController animated:NO];
    ...
}
```

To remove from the screen use the following:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Yeah, I have that, must have missed the animation when viewing. too many hours = screenface

Comment: Sorry to be dense: does that fix your problem, or is it still not working the way you want it to?